# How to find full module path of a class to import in other file

Tags: python, path

I have method that returns module path of given class name

```
def findModulePath(path, className):
    attributes = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for source in (s for s in files if s.endswith(".py")):
            name = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(source))[0]
            full_name = os.path.splitext(source)[0].replace(os.path.sep, '.')
            m = imp.load_module(full_name, *imp.find_module(name, [root]))
            try:
                attr = getattr(m, className)
                attributes.append(attr)
            #                if "." in attr.__module__:
            #                    return

            except:
                pass
    if len(attributes) <= 0:
        raise Exception, "Class %s not found" % className

    for element in attributes:
        print "%s.%s" % (element.__module__, className)
```

but it does not return the full path of the module,
For example I have a python file named "objectmodel" in objects package,and it contains a Model class, So I call findModulePath(MyProjectPath,"Model"). it prints objectmodel.Model but I need objects.objectmodel.Model

Comment: I've replaced base packages path in the __file__ and then replacing / with .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The attribute you're looking for is `__file__`.  Note you may have to do some massaging of this value after you get it - it could be a `.py`, `.pyc`, `.pyd`, `.so`, `.dll`, etc.

Of course it's also going to be a full path, but you have your root which you can subtract to get the actual hierarchy that you care about.